# python multiple inheritance qustion

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

This is an interview example question I copied and modified from question 10 of:
https://www.codementor.io/sheena/essential-python-interview-questions-du107ozr6

```
class A(object):
    def go(self):
        print("go A go!")
    def stop(self):
        print("stop A stop!")

class B(A):
    def go(self):
        super(B, self).go()
        print("go B go!")

class C(A):
    def go(self):
        super(C, self).go()
        print("go C go!")
    def stop(self):
        super(C, self).stop()
        print("stop C stop!")

class D(B,C):
    def go(self):
        super(D, self).go()
        print("go D go!")
    def stop(self):
        super(D, self).stop()
        print("stop D stop!")

class E(B,C): pass
a = A()
b = B()
c = C()
d = D()
e = E()
print "call b.stop()......."
b.stop()
print "call d.stop()......."
d.stop()
print "call e.stop()......."
e.stop()
```

answer is:

```
call b.stop().......
stop A stop!
call d.stop().......
stop A stop!
stop C stop!    
stop D stop!  #?why not having b.stop() which leads to "stop A stop!"
call e.stop().......
stop A stop!
stop C stop!
```

I understand calling b.stop() shows "stop A stop!" because b does not override stop() so will inherit stop() from A.

But I do not understand why calling d.stop() only show stop of A,C,D, not ACBD, isn't MRO: D->B->C->A?

and I do not understand why calling e.stop() only shows stop of A and C, based on MRO: E->B->C->A, I think e.stop() should inherit from B's stop(), so should be stop A stop, stop C stop, then stop B stop?

I must have misunderstand sth. about super I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand calling b.stop() shows "stop A stop!" because b does not
>   override stop() so will inherit stop() from A.
>
> But I do not understand why calling d.stop() only show stop of A,C,D,
>   not ACBD, isn't MRO: D->B->C->A?

B inherits `stop` from A, but what that means is that when you try to access `B.stop` or `some_B_instance.stop`, the attribute search will find the method through `A.__dict__` after looking in `B.__dict__`. It doesn't put the method in the `B` class directly.

When `super` follows the MRO of a D instance, class B comes after D, but `super` is only interested in looking at B itself at this point, not B's ancestors. It looks in `B.__dict__` for a `stop` entry, without considering inherited methods; inherited methods will be handled later in the search, when `super` reaches the classes those methods are inherited from.

Since inheriting methods doesn't actually put them in `B.__dict__`, `super` doesn't find `stop` in `B`.

Comment: ok, so "super is only interested in looking at B itself not ancestor", . got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`B` does not have its own `stop` (you'll notice the string `"stop B stop"` never appears in the code), so it will never be executed. In other worse, since there is no line of code which could possibly print "stop B stop", it will not be printed.

Comment: but calling b.stop() shows "stop A stop!", which means b.stop() is available?

Comment: Yes but it shows up as `stop A stop!` even though it is b.stop

Comment: B does not have *its own* stop. It inherits `stop` from `A`.