# Ambiguous output using super() function

Tags: python

I am trying to get the output of below python code containing super() function.

```
class A(object):
    def go(self):
        print("go A go!")
    def stop(self):
        print("stop A stop!")
    def pause(self):
        raise Exception("Not Implemented")

class B(A):
    def go(self):
        super(B, self).go()
        print("go B go!")

class C(A):
    def go(self):
        super(C, self).go()
        print("go C go!")
    def stop(self):
        super(C, self).stop()
        print("stop C stop!")

class D(B,C):
    def go(self):
        super(D, self).go()
        print("go D go!")
    def stop(self):
        super(D, self).stop()
        print("stop D stop!")
    def pause(self):
        print("wait D wait!")
class E(B,C): pass

a = A()
b = B()
c = C()
d = D()
e = E()


#Find output of below function calls
d.go()
b.stop()
```

My questions are:

1. Why the output of `d.go()` is:

   ```
   go A go!
   go C go!
   go B go!
   go D go!
   ```

   Shouldn't there be one extra "go A go!" in output as class B and C both is calling method go of base class A using super() function?
2. As there is no stop() function in Class B, then why `b.stop()` is returning "stop A stop!" rather than raising an error?

Comment: 1. No, the whole point of `super` is that it makes sure each superclass method gets called *once*. 2. Because it's inherited the implementation from A, as the output makes pretty clear?

Comment: [This looks familiar.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335165/python-multiple-inheritance-qustion)

Comment: 2. B inherits from A so it will have a stop method due to inheritance.

Comment: 1. No there shouldn't, see [super considered super](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/amp/). 2. No, why should it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python multiple inheritance qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335165/python-multiple-inheritance-qustion)

Answer (score 0):

`super` in Python does not give you a "straight line" result with all ancestors in each subclass, in order.

Rather, it is really well thought to "do the right thing" when it comes to multiple inheritance - and a fundamental piece of the "right thing" is exactly avoiding a method in one of the superclasses to be called more than once.

So, to start with, whenever you create a class in Python, that class gains a `__mro__` attribute (method resolution order). The first class there is always the class itself, and the last is always `object` .

`super()` will search the classes in the order they appear in the `__mro__` in order to retrieve an attribute, method, or a superclass attribute or method. [This is the documente describing the MRO linearization algorithm, that started to beused with Python 2.3 and is in use up to today](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)  .

You will find out that under these rules, your MRO for the class D is `(D, B, C,A, object)` that is -  if the original invocation of a method was in a `D` object, when `super` is encountered in the method's implementation in `B` it will call `C` implementation, because C is the next class in D's `__mro__`. The document linked above has the rationale for that and more examples, but TL;DR: this ensures that each upstream class has the chance to be called at least and at most once, if all methods involved use `super` in a collaborative way.

As for

> As there is no stop() function in Class B, then why b.stop() is
>   returning "stop A stop!" rather than raising an error?

That is basic inheritance that does not need one to understand the specifics of Python's `super`: a superclass method is used if it is not overriden in the subclass.